# Mysql Forcing close of thread 946 user

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.1

My mysql box keeping shutting down and up. Below is snippet of the log file. There is quite a number of places I notice this Forcing close of thread 946  user:

```
130426 12:36:28 [Note] Event Scheduler: Purging the queue. 0 events
130426 12:36:28  InnoDB: Starting shutdown...
130426 12:36:31  InnoDB: Shutdown completed; log sequence number 0 1111309
130426 12:36:31 [Note] /usr/libexec/mysqld: Shutdown complete

130426 12:36:31 mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid ended
130426 12:36:32 mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /var/lib/mysql
130426 12:36:32  InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 8.0M
130426 12:36:32  InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
130426 12:36:32  InnoDB: Started; log sequence number 0 1111309
130426 12:36:32 [Note] Event Scheduler: Loaded 0 events
130426 12:36:32 [Note] /usr/libexec/mysqld: ready for connections.
Version: '5.1.67'  socket: '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock'  port: 3306  Source distribution
130426 21:05:19 [Note] /usr/libexec/mysqld: Normal shutdown

130426 21:05:19 [Note] Event Scheduler: Purging the queue. 0 events
130426 21:05:21 [Warning] /usr/libexec/mysqld: Forcing close of thread 946  user: ''

130426 21:05:22  InnoDB: Starting shutdown...
130426 21:05:23  InnoDB: Shutdown completed; log sequence number 0 1111309
130426 21:05:23 [Note] /usr/libexec/mysqld: Shutdown complete

130426 21:05:23 mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid ended
130426 21:05:25 mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /var/lib/mysql
130426 21:05:25  InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 8.0M
130426 21:05:25  InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
130426 21:05:25  InnoDB: Started; log sequence number 0 1111309
130426 21:05:25 [Note] Event Scheduler: Loaded 0 events
130426 21:05:25 [Note] /usr/libexec/mysqld: ready for connections.
Version: '5.1.67'  socket: '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock'  port: 3306  Source distribution
130428  0:47:12 [Note] /usr/libexec/mysqld: Normal shutdown

130428  0:47:12 [Note] Event Scheduler: Purging the queue. 0 events
130428  0:47:12  InnoDB: Starting shutdown...
130428  0:47:16  InnoDB: Shutdown completed; log sequence number 0 1111309
130428  0:47:16 [Note] /usr/libexec/mysqld: Shutdown complete
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be one of those errors that won't go away. In this case, it may be a case of human error.

First of all, here are a series of links with similar error messages on Shutdowns

- http://www.webhostingtalk.com/showthread.php?t=518682
- http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=7403
- http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=48879
- http://lists.mysql.com/mysql/206094
- http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/error-log.html (See User Comments)
- http://www.mail-archive.com/mysql@lists.mysql.com/msg12324.html

They all have seem to have one thing in common: MySQL for Windows.

It was claimed that [Bug 7403 (the second link)](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=7403) was fixed and patch implemented July 14, 2005: http://lists.mysql.com/internals/27091

The versions of MySQL that this fix should be in 4.0, 5.0.40, 5.1.42. Looking in the error log you posted, I see you are using MySQL 5.1.67. Apparently, no one knows how to fix this issue or wants to (http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=7403) I also noted that the error messages indicate that you are using MySQL in Linux already.

I have three(3) suggestions that range from the most passive to the most aggressive...

## SUGGESTION #1

Try setting [**log_warnings**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/server-options.html#option_mysqld_log-warnings) to 0, if you don't mind flying blind on warnings.

## SUGGESTION #2

Upgrade to MySQL 5.6.11. Hopefully, there is should be more updates and bug fixes for this.

## SUGGESTION #3

Move the Database to Linux. There should be more stability for this problem away on a better machine with the most updated kernel for the OS.

Give it a Try !!!

## UPDATE 2013-04-30 11:20 EDT

Here is the fastest way to check for table corruption

Comment: Its already running on a centos 6.4 machine what else should i do thx.

Comment: The past of least resistance would be SUGGESTION #1: Setting log_warnings to 0 and restarting mysql.

Comment: ok will do with suggestion #1 but what effect it will havecon mysql box will i stop to receive warnings?

Comment: some say is due to table corruption what is your opinion on this?

Comment: Is all your data InnoDB ???

Comment: No some is myisam could those be the culprit?